# How do I factor out common rules in a Material UI style object?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following set of style rules:

```
  status_in_progress: {
    fontSize: 14,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.dark,
    padding: 2,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    display: "inline-block",
  },
  status_complete: {
    fontSize: 14,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    padding: 2,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    display: "inline-block",
  },
  status_overdue: {
    fontSize: 14,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.error.dark,
    padding: 2,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    display: "inline-block",
  },
```

As you can see, much of this is identical. I'd love to be able to define a set of rules like this:

```
  status: {
    fontSize: 14,
    padding: 2,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    display: "inline-block",
    in_progress: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.dark,
    },
    complete: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    },
    ...
  },
```

But it seems like MUI does not like that. What's the most efficient way to factor out the common rules?

I am also using ReactJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we write CSS styles inside a JS object, the keys of the object get parsed to find the corresponding CSS property. For example, inside your `status` object, the key `fontSize` is parsed into `font-size`, which is a valid CSS property.

However, in your refactored code, you have included keys of `in_progress` and `complete`, which do not correspond to any valid CSS properties. Therefore, the parser has trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve with these keys.

You can try the following refactoring:

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  status: {
    fontSize: 14,
    padding: 2,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    display: "inline-block",
  },
  in_progress: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.dark,
  },
  complete: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
  },
  overdue: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.error.dark,
  }
});

function ExampleComponent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
     <div>
        <p className={clsx(classes.status, classes.in_progress)}>Sample Text</p>
     </div>
  )
}
```

I moved the `in_progress`, `complete` and `overdue` keys outside the `status` object.

In my sample code, I added two classes of `classes.status` and `classes.in_progress` to an element. This is equivalent of adding `classes.status_in_progress` before you re-factor your code:

```
<p className={clsx(classes.status, classes.in_progress)}>Sample Text</p>
```

Note that [`clsx()`](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#whats-the-clsx-dependency-for) is a tiny utility that is pre-installed in your project that allows you to construct `className` strings easier. [The repo of `clsx`](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx) lists more examples on how you can use it. If you don't want to use `clsx()`, the following code works the same:

```
<p className={`${classes.status} ${classes.in_progress}`}>Sample Text</p>
```

I prefer `clsx()` because the template string syntax can get tedious sometimes. If you want to use `clsx()`, **remember to import it** by adding `import clsx from "clsx";` at the top of the file.

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't scratch my itch to have an object hierarchy, but at least it's efficient, and in the end it's just styling.